# How do I find the annual number of new event guests in a list that spans over many years with repeat guests (Google Data Studio)?

Tags: looker-studio

I have a list of guests that come to my events. The list contains 10 years worth of events and guests. I want to know how many new guests are brand new each year, such that they've never attended my events before. How do I calculate this in the calculated field?

For example, John attended my event in 2011, 2012, and 2013. This means John was my new guest in 2011, but not 2012 or 2013. Therefore, the count of new guests in 2011 increments by one.

It is safe to assume that John uses the same email each time he registers for my event. Therefore, my resulting table should look like this:

| Email | First Year of Attendance |
| --- | --- |
| johndoe@live.com | 2011 |

Answer (score 1):

## 0) Summary

- Use **EITHER** #1 **OR** #2
- #1: Use if two fields are required (`Email` and `First_Year`)
- #2: Use if three fields are required (`Email`, `Year` and `First_Year`)

## 1) Aggregate `Year` by [`MIN`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583210)

If the goal is only to show the 2 fields in the [Table](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7189044), then  simply add the `Year` field as a Metric and aggregate by [`MIN`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583210):

[image]

## 2) Data Blending

To display all three fields in a single Table, one approach is using a Self [Data Blend](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9061420); the below does the trick where `Email` represents the field with Emails (such as `johndoe@live.com`) and `Year` the field with Year values, which can be a Number field (for example `2011`) or a Date field (such as `01 Jan 2011`):

### 2.1) Data Blending

[image]

**Data Source 1**

- ***Join Key***: `Email`
- ***Dimension***: `Year`

**Data Source 2**

- ***Join Key***: `Email`
- ***Metric***: `First_Year`; Rename: `Year`; Aggregation: [`MIN`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583210)
  [image]

### 2.2) [Table](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7189044)

- ***Data Source***: Blended Data Source
- ***Dimension 1***: `Email`
- ***Dimension 2***: `First_Year`
- ***Dimension 3***: `Year`

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/ce7c6c53-d941-4034-a3ed-b3b36660580d) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Hd0FFEnD8DwBbLk9VT7HIZuuY1JV-pcb7stqOAWoNpA/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]